# PayPal Developer Account & API ..what happens if account is limited?

Tags: api, paypal

I have a hypothetical question about my PayPal developer account. Since the app I developed uses an `API Username` (`myname-facilitator_api1.mydomain.com`), `API Password` and `API Signature` to do the transactions, I am wondering what happens with the API access if my PayPal account for whatever reason becomes limited?

I've had my account limited in the past because I did a large withdrawal and PayPal asked me to send in documents to lift the limits ...but what happens during that time to the API access? Would customers also not be able to do transactions through my app during this time or how would it be affected?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Paypal policies rather than programming

Comment: Not really. It's about programming because it involves the API access. And there's no other PayPal forum for programmers. PayPal themselves actually link to this forum in the dashboard for technical questions.

Comment: The fact that PayPal points its developers here (without having talked to SO previously) doesn't mean that every question about the PayPal API is on topic here. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296339/reach-out-to-paypal-about-outsourcing-their-support-to-stack-overflow

Comment: I understand what you mean. I also found this post here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173138/is-stack-overflow-the-official-paypal-support-site where SO says it's okay for PayPal to do so. If my post bothers you too much please ignore it. It's a genuine question.

Comment: No, it's okay to ask PayPal related *developer* questions here. Questions about API policies are not covered by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple types of account limitations. For most limitations you can continue to accept payments. In other cases not.

If PayPal is uncertain about whether an account may have been compromised, or lacks a required piece of paperwork, they will generally only limit withdrawals so that the merchant can continue their business with as little impact as possible while they resolve the issue.

If PayPal determines that an account is fraudulent, or engaged in some type of enterprise for which PayPal cannot process the payments, they will block acceptance as well in order to protect the payers -- the alternative being to accept but then reverse all the transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when your accounts becomes limited you can still receive payments. You can't withdraw though.